# Android Flickr Oauth invalid_signature while getting the request token

Tags: android, oauth, flickr

I am trying to create a flickr app on android but am stuck right at authentication for requesting a request token.

Generating Signature

The APi key:-496a8ac6ca46325e6cef************

Api Secret:-685682a92*******

The base String:-
             `GET&http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fservices%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dsoft%253A%252F%252Fcom.alice.testflickr%26oauth_consumer_key%3D496a8ac6ca46325e6cef%26oauth_nonce%3D394e61453f7b82cd633d229ac9b6454b%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1339654651%26oauth_version%3D1.0`

Method to generate signature:-

```
     public String computeSignature(String baseString,String key)throws IllegalStateException, UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException{
            //here key is the appsecret+"&"
            byte[] byteHMAC = null;
     Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
     SecretKeySpec spec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(),"HmacSHA1");
     mac.init(spec);
     byteHMAC = mac.doFinal(baseString.getBytes("UTF-8"));

     return new String(Base64.encode(byteHMAC,Base64.NO_WRAP));
}
```

Timestamp is `(System.currentTimeMillis)/1000`

Nonce is `Long.toString(System.nanoTime());`

I request for a request token like this:-

```
http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token?oauth_nonce=12190496931948&oauth_timestamp=1339664498&oauth_consumer_key=496a8ac6ca46325e6cef&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=jg8CCdKb8gw%2BMJK0aJ6Brpba0G0%3D&oauth_callback=soft%3A%2F%2Fcom.alice.testflickr
```

But I always end up getting

```
oauth_problem=signature_invalid&debug_sbs=GET&http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fservices%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dsoft%253A%252F%252Fcom.alice.testflickr%26oauth_consumer_key%3D496a8ac6ca46325e6cef%26oauth_nonce%3D12190496931948%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1339664498%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

Is there something wrong with the way i am generating the signature or is there any other issue here.
EDIT:the value of timestamp in the basestring and the request is the same

Answer (score 0):

Flickr documentation says that the signing process should go like this:

> All API calls using an authentication token must be signed. In
> addition, calls to the flickr.auth.* methods and redirections to the
> auth page on flickr must also be signed.
>
> The process of signing is as follows.
>
> - Sort your argument list into alphabetical order based on the parameter name.
>   e.g.
>   foo=1, bar=2, baz=3 sorts to bar=2, baz=3, foo=1
> - concatenate the shared secret and argument name-value pairs
>   e.g.
>   SECRETbar2baz3foo1
> - calculate the md5() hash of this string
> - append this value to the argument list with the name api_sig, in hexidecimal string form
>   e.g.
>   api_sig=1f3870be274f6c49b3e31a0c6728957f